# Kinect not being detected on other computers after deployment of UWP

Tags: deployment, uwp, camera, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

I recently finished to develop a UWP based on the SDK example [CameraFrames](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames). On the second screen of this example (and also on my app) you can choose to preview the frames taken by the Kinect v2.0 as shown below.

[image: image showing how it works on my own PC]

On the top of the image on the right of "Grupo de fontes" (Source group) I am able to choose between the different cameras that are connected to my PC. The problem comes when I deploy my app to another PC, I am unable to see "Kinect V2 Video Sensor". Thus rendering my app obsolete as it needs to be portable between PCs. I have checked that inside "Package.appxmanifest->Capabilities->Web Cam" checkbox is ticked.

I am out of ideas as I don't have a clue why my app works flawlesly on my computer but not on the rest. If you need any extra info to help me with my problem please let me know.

It is worth noting that on the other PCs that I've tried my app can read frames via Kinect Studio or MatLab.

Inside "Camera privacy settings" my app has privileges to use the camera.

Thank you in advance.

**Update due to Nico Zhu's comment**

My OS is Windows 10 and my target version is "10.0.16299.0". I have downloading and deploying [CameraFrames](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames) on the second computer that I'm working with but it doesn't recognize the Kinect as in input source. Even though CameraFrames doesn't work doesn't read anything, I can properly make use of the kinect using Kinect Studio.

It seems that my problem is focused on my second computer not being able to make use of the Kinect on any deployed UWPs. What should I installed in order to make sure that I have all that's needed to properly read from the Kinect?

Comment: Could you provide your OS version and the target version of the project? Dose this problem could be reproduced by the CameraFrames sample? If not, could you please share me a sample to reproduce this?

Comment: I have updated my answer to adress your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of a lot of headaches I just needed to upgrade my drivers.